# Youtube iFrame custom orientation

Tags: javascript, android, iframe, youtube, youtube-api

I am trying to use youtube iFrame in my app. When I click on the full screen mode the video stretches vertically as a reel because the content in the video is like that. But I want to make the full screen mode horizontal. How can I do it using javascript or html?
I tried using css but the iframe somehow overrides my css injection. I injected my css using javascript in inline.

```
<iFrame>
```